# exec-maven-plugin plugin error

Tags: maven-3, exec-maven-plugin

I use the exec-maven-plugin as follow

```
<plugin>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <version>1.6.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>npm install</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <configuration>
                <executable>${npm.executable}</executable>
                <arguments>
                  <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/target/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
                <target>
                  <echo message="Npm install" />
                </target>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have the following error

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/angular5/tourism"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

However the directory "/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/angular5/tourism" exists and the command npm install works in this directory in the console. I have the Apache Maven 3.5.4 installed and use eclipse

Answer (score 3):

First, you should edit your question as I mentionned in comments below.

Then, I think you misunderstood the error. In fact, the error indicates that `npm` is not found inside your directory `"/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/angular5/tourism`.

And this is normal. `npm` is in your `PATH` that's why you can run `npm install` successfully.

I recommand you to use a **Maven plugin** for npm commands:

- [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)
- [npm-maven-plugin](https://github.com/aseovic/npm-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Adding -PlocalNoDeploy as part of your mvn command might resolve this issue.

Comment: Finally I used frontend-maven-plugin and solved my issue. I have another question about Mickaël B remark. If I add a comment, I have not all the editor options. The only way to have all the editor options is add an answer. How can I get out from this ?